# rolling_sum for irregular time series in pandas?

Tags: pandas, time-series

I've got a time series with irregular sampling and would like use a function like `pandas.stats.moments.rolling_sum` on it.

Unfortunately it looks like the function only goes back "x" samples, not "x" seconds.

Not sure how to get around this... pretty new to pandas.

My data looks like

```
time     value
0.000    0.0000
0.013    0.0134
0.023    0.0256
0.035    0.0423
0.049    0.0756
0.069    0.0998
```

Comment: are these timedelta times?, float-like times, or actual times (datelike)?

Comment: time delta, starting at zero. I'm using pandas for analyzing data for physical testing.

Comment: ok...solution below as we don't offer timedelta support for this ATM. You could also do this with a groupby but I think would be slower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do what I think you want

```
In [34]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='\s+')
```

Create a datelike-index (assume you mean seconds here, need to convert to ns to add to the date)

```
In [35]: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime([Timestamp('20130101').value + v*1e9 for v in df['time'] ])

In [36]: df.set_index('time',inplace=True)

In [37]: df
Out[37]: 
                             value
time                              
2013-01-01 00:00:00         0.0000
2013-01-01 00:00:00.012999  0.0134
2013-01-01 00:00:00.023000  0.0256
2013-01-01 00:00:00.035000  0.0423
2013-01-01 00:00:00.048999  0.0756
2013-01-01 00:00:00.068999  0.0998
```

Conform the results to 20ms, rolling 20 periods with no minimum

```
In [38]: pd.rolling_sum(df,20,0,freq='20ms')
Out[38]: 
                              value
time                               
2013-01-01 00:00:00         0.00670
2013-01-01 00:00:00.020000  0.04065
2013-01-01 00:00:00.040000  0.11625
2013-01-01 00:00:00.060000  0.21605
```

Comment: Why is this accepted? It is not a rolling sum with irregular times.